# php form: take user back to previous page from register form

Tags: php

Tried various solution from stack overflow and internet but none seems to be working. My php registration page is a modal window form. what I am looking for is to take the user back to the page from where he redirected to login form.

Register link:

```
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SIGN UP</a>
```

Register processing:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once("config.php");
require_once("all_functions.php");
$cust_email = stripslashes($_POST['cust_email']);
$cust_password = stripslashes($_POST['cust_password']););




$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE cust_email = '$cust_email'");
if (mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
    {
    echo 'That email is already registered';
    exit;
    }
mysql_query("INSERT INTO register (`cust_email`, `cust_password`) 
VALUES
('$cust_email', '$cust_password')");
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = $cust_email;
    header("Location: http://tre.com/");
    exit;
?>
```

function to check user is logged in  or not

```
<?php
function check_valid_user()
// see if somebody is logged in and notify them if not
{
global $_SESSION;
if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
{
return $_SESSION['valid_user'];
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the address from where user have registered and apply it in either of this ways
to directly take user back to previous page from register form without giving any message use

```
header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

but if you want to display an message you can use this code

```
echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT="0; url='.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'">
 Your registration was sucessfull you will be redirected automatically. If not, please <a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'">click here</a>.';
```

Hope it Helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```